Do Hindus agree on the existence of a "good" person?
Hi I am asking this question for a school essay, and the topic is. "There is no such thing as a good person, Discuss". I am exploring the viewpoints of different religions and philosophies on this topic and would like to hear an answer from Hinduism, Buddhism, Jainism etc. I have researched concepts such as Atman, karma, Anatta etc and how they would relate. I would like more clarification on someone more knowledgeable. thanks.

Yes, there is a concept of a good person in Hindu scriptures.
In the Bhagavad Gita, 16th chapter, Lord Krishna lists out the qualities of a person born with divine nature (good person).

16.1 The Blessed Lord said - Fearlessness, purity of mind, persistence in knowledge and yoga, charity and control of the external organs, sacrifice, (scriptural) study, austerity and recititude...


16.2 Non-injury, truthfulness, absence of anger, renunciation, control of the internal organ, absence of vilification, kindness to creatures, non-covetousness, gentleness, modesty, freedom from restlessness;...


16.3 Vigour, forgiveness, fortitude, purity, freedom from malice, absence of haughtiness-these, O scion of the Bharata dynasty, are (the qualities) of one born destined to have the divine nature.

